# Get list of items within a List

Tags: elixir

I have the following result in a variable :

```
list_of_scripts = [
  {<<"script">>,[{<<"type">>,<<"text/javascript">>}],[<<"\n            /*\n some JS here;\n                ">>]},            
  {<<"script">>,[{<<"type">>,<<"text/javascript">>}],["some json content"]},
  {<<"script">>,[],[<<"\n ">>]}
]
```

I want to get the 3rd element of each tuple into a list

Comment: It has to be a list :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a list of the third element of each tuple you can use `Enum.map/2` + `elem/2`:

```
list_of_scripts |> Enum.map(&elem(&1, 2)) |> IO.inspect
```

```
[["\n            /*\n some JS here;\n                "], ["some json content"],
 ["\n "]]
```

If you a flat list (since every 3rd element is a list), you can use `Enum.flat_map/2` instead:

```
list_of_scripts |> Enum.flat_map(&elem(&1, 2)) |> IO.inspect
```

```
["\n            /*\n some JS here;\n                ", "some json content",
 "\n "]
```

`elem` is zero indexed, so to get the third item, we use `elem(_, 2)`.